# Gprs server setup and data sending

Tags: sql-server, gps, server, gprs

I recently bought a gps tracker with gsm and Gprs support, I want to send data from gps to my GPRS server(located in my house) and from there to use data..., my problem is that I don't know how to set up GPRS server, what do I need, which programs etc, my gps has fallowing settings: configure APN, GPRS user name and password, IP and port setup, 
Gps has ability to send data via GPRS.
I am sorry for this kind a question, but I really do not know much about servers, my love is programming.
I need this kind of stuff to make program for gps tracking (amateur off course)